# How to add 2 sequential SSH connection through paramiko in python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh, postgresql-9.1, paramiko

I can connect to postgres server as below

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
self.ssh.connect('hostname', username='uname')
```

But I have to connect to another server after I connect to first one.
So in terminal

- first: `ssh uname@hostname`
- second: `ssh uname2@hostname@` (in server 1)

How do I this in python code? I tried

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
self.ssh.connect('hostname', username='uname')
self.ssh.connect('hostname2', username='uname2')
```

But this doesn't work

I tried to use transport but couldn't get concept clear

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  so looking at the link I see  transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname) then do connect for first hostname and then forward tunnel to second hostname? Do I need to do connect for second hostname again? And I also couldn't import forward library..